# How to make onClick in Custom Adapter into a button

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement the function `onClick` in the `CustomAdapter` into a button so that I can call an action. I want to make it so that when the user clicks on the recycler item, the `onClick` function calls `openTopSheet()` that is from `MainActivity` which brings down the top sheet. In essence, how can I make it so that `onClick` can perform a method from MainActivity? Any help would be appreciated

CustomAdapter.kt

```
class CustomAdapter(val modelList: List<Model>, val context: Context) :

    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        (holder as ViewHolder).bind(modelList.get(position));
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        return ViewHolder(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return modelList.size;
    }

    lateinit var mClickListener: ClickListener

    fun setOnItemClickListener(aClickListener: ClickListener) {

        mClickListener = aClickListener
    }

    interface ClickListener {
        fun onClick(pos: Int, aView: () -> Unit)

    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView), View.OnClickListener {

        var r = MainActivity()

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)

        }

        override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

            r.openTopSheet()

        }

        fun bind(model: Model): Unit {
            itemView.txt.text = model.name
            itemView.sub_txt.text = model.version

            val id = context.resources.getIdentifier(model.name.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT), "drawable", context.packageName)
            itemView.img.setBackgroundResource(id)
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), BottomSheetRecyclerViewAdapter.ListTappedListener {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.home_page)
}

  fun openTopSheet() {
        topSheetBehavior.state = TopSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        topSheetBehavior.setTopSheetCallback(object : TopSheetBehavior.TopSheetCallback() {
            override fun onSlide(bottomSheet: View, slideOffset: Float, isOpening: Boolean?) {

            }

            override fun onStateChanged(bottomSheet: View, newState: Int) {
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In ViewHolder:**

```
bind(model: Model, openTopSheet: ()->Unit)

itemView.button.setOnClickListener{
    openTopSheet.invoke()
}
```

**In adapter:**

```
class CustomAdapter(
    val modelList: List<Model>, 
    val context: Context,
    val openTopSheet: ()->Unit)
)

(holder as ViewHolder).bind(modelList.get(position), openTopSheet);
```

**In Activity:**

```
val adapter = CustomAdapter(listOf(), this, { openTopSheet() } )
```

And you need to add openTopSheet method in activity.

Comment: thank you. I was able to put everything in. looks like it works but it fails at 
itemView.button.setOnClickListener{openTopSheet.invoke()} when I put it on onClick.

Comment: Sorry meant when i put it in bind()